# Recursion function confusion for decimal to binary code?

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion, binary, decimal

```
decimal = int(input("Enter the Decimal value :"))

def d_b(decimal,binary):
    # function to convert decimal to binary
    binary = binary + str(decimal % 2)
    if decimal > 1:
        d_b(decimal//2,binary)
    else :
        print (binary)
        return (binary)

print ("Decimal to Binary : ", d_b(decimal,binary = ''))
```

Output for input 34:

010001

Decimal to Binary :  None

The function prints the answer but doesn't return it and then starts going back to function and starts deleting characters one by one from the string and finally returns none instead of the binary string.

**Correct Code :**

```
decimal = int(input("Enter the Decimal value :"))

def d_b(decimal,binary):
    # function to convert decimal to binary
    if decimal > 0:
        binary = d_b(int(decimal)//2,binary)
        binary = binary + str(decimal % 2)
    return (binary)

print ("Decimal to Binary :",d_b(decimal,binary = ''))
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. The underlying algorithm seems to be incorrect. I suggest you get it working as a script before attempting to package it as a function

Comment: missing `return` in the `if` branch (before recursive call to `d_b`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, your welcome:

```
def d_b(decimal,binary):
    # function to convert decimal to binary
    binary = binary + str(decimal % 2)
    if decimal > 1:
        binary = d_b(int(decimal/2), binary) # <-- this is the line you should change
    return binary
```

Or even shorter with the ternary operator:

```
return decimal > 1 ? d_b(int(decimal/2), binary): binary
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but if you could help me figure out what was going wrong with my code(how compiler was seeing it) why did it printed the output but return None.

Comment: Because you did not assign the value that you called recusively.See at my comment in line 5